# Converting static library to DLL causes access violation before main

Tags: c++, windows, dll, visual-studio-2015, googletest

We have a large solution in VS2015 with two libraries and numerous win32 projects for testing our application. Our projects and their dependencies are as follows:

- Event Library

  - winmm.dll (for timing functions)
- App Library

  - eventLibrary.lib (static)
- Test Case

  - eventLibrary.lib (static)
  - appLibrary.lib (static)
  - gtestd.lib (static, Google Test framework)

The libraries were originally static, but we're converting them to DLLs for faster linking. I've modified our app code with `__declspec(dllexport)` decorators, and have successfully compiled and linked our app as a DLL. All testcases which do not use `eventLibrary.lib` built and ran successfully, the rest crashed because `eventLibrary.lib` was statically linked in both `appLibrary.dll` and `testCase.exe`.

I converted `eventLibrary.lib` to a DLL, which builds and links with our exes but crashes before they reach `main`. I'm using a def file rather than modifying the library sources. If I remove the `eventLibrary.dll` dependency from `testCase.exe` and export its symbols from `appLibrary.dll`, the exact same crash occurs.

The crash is in `ostream` inside the overloaded `<<` operator. The `stringstream` (argument `_Ostr` below) being passed in is identical as when building with static libraries. I get an `0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0D20E4E9`, which appears to be caused by calling the `width` method:

```
template<class _Traits> inline
    basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& operator<<(
        basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& _Ostr,
        const char *_Val)
    {   // insert NTBS into char stream
    typedef char _Elem;
    typedef basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits> _Myos;
    ios_base::iostate _State = ios_base::goodbit;
    streamsize _Count = (streamsize)_Traits::length(_Val);  // may overflow
    streamsize _Pad = _Ostr.width() <= 0 || _Ostr.width() <= _Count
        ? 0 : _Ostr.width() - _Count; // <- Dies here
```

This occurs during initialization of globals in the Google Test framework, which is still a static library. The call stack is as follows:

> testCase.exe!testing::Message::operator<<(const char[7] & val) Line 131
>       testCase.exe!testing::internal::FlagToEnvVar(const char * flag) Line 1136
>       testCase.exe!testing::internal::BoolFromGTestEnv(const char * flag, bool default_value) Line 1195
>       testCase.exe!testing::`dynamic initializer for 'FLAGS_gtest_also_run_disabled_tests''() Line 202

Is dynamically linking our event library somehow corrupting memory in `testCase.exe`? Could this have anything to do with DLLs having their own heaps? I've ensure that our DLLs and exes are compiled using the same runtime (`/MDd`) and identical flags when building and linking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by placing both library sources within the same DLL. Our event library actually has macros defined for exporting to a DLL, and we've eliminated any dependency issues by combining the two.